# How to add a title to a histogram graph?

Tags: r, graph, histogram, title, tapply

I have a set of data named `ais`. This data set is in the package `sn` in `R`. I used the following codes to read this data set:

```
library(sn)
data(ais)
attach(ais)
```

This data shows information (such as the gender, sport, height, weight, etc.) of 202 athletics.

I used `tapply` to draw the histograms of each sport (frequency of heights). My code is as follow:

```
par(mfrow = c(3, 4))
tapply(Ht,sport,hist)
```

The result of the codes are below pics:
[image]
My question is, how can I show/add **the title of each sport** (the name of the sport) on its corresponding histogram?

Answer (score 1):

We can `split` the data, and use `main` as the names of the `list`

```
lst1 <- with(ais, split(Ht, sport))
par(mfrow = c(3, 4))
Map(function(x, y) hist(x, main = y), lst1, names(lst1))
```

-output

[image]